# How do you get computed cursor type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouse-cursor

I want to change an element when the cursor changes its type, for instance when the cursor changes from pointer to a text (I-beam).

I have tried to use

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const computed = window.getComputedStyle(tgt)["cursor"]
  console.log("Computed: " + computed)
});
```

but this just logs "Computed: auto". I want the know the cursor type specifically. I don't know if this is possible?

Comment: You don't need `getComputedStyle()` for this. You only need to access: `theElementReference.style.cursor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to define cursor style for one of your elements like this:

```
<style>

#cur{
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
```

and then when mouseover on your element, it will change from auto to pionter

```
 <div id="cur">mouse over</div>

<script>


document.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const computed = window.getComputedStyle(tgt)["cursor"]
  
  
    if(computed !== "auto"){
        console.log(computed);
    }

});


</script>
```

Comment: FYI: `window.getComputedStyle(tgt)["cursor"]` can be written as: `getComputedStyle(tgt).cursor`

Answer (score 0):

I think logging `tgt.style.cursor` should do the trick.

Comment: It will be `undefined` if not specified explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

- We are checking whether the cursor property is changing or not.
- `hasCursorChange` which is default `false` and we are setting it to true by making if condition false whenever cursor changes.
- Just for the visual understanding I am adding change class and applying CSS for `background-color` so you can have better idea of it.
- You can play with if condition or adding event listener for any other elements or child, this on will work for every element of `DOM`.

```js
document.addEventListener(
  "mouseover",
  function(e) {
    var hasCusrorChnaged = false;
    var cursor = e.target.style.cursor;
    if (cursor != "") {
      if (!hasCusrorChnaged) {
        e.target.classList.add("change");
      }
    }
  },
  false
);
```

```css
.change {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Mouse over the words to change the cursor.</h1>
<span style="cursor:auto">auto</span><br>
<span style="cursor:crosshair">crosshair</span><br>
<span style="cursor:default">default</span><br>
<span style="cursor:e-resize">e-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:grab">grab</span><br>
<span style="cursor:help">help</span><br>
<span style="cursor:move">move</span><br>
<span style="cursor:n-resize">n-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:ne-resize">ne-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:nw-resize">nw-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:pointer">pointer</span><br>
<span style="cursor:progress">progress</span><br>
<span style="cursor:s-resize">s-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:se-resize">se-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:sw-resize">sw-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:text">text</span><br>
<span style="cursor:w-resize">w-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:wait">wait</span><br>
<span style="cursor:not-allowed">not-allowed</span><br>
<span style="cursor:no-drop">no-drop</span><br>
```